# Strange Bug(?) in Xcode ,Every new project opens with same existing code

Tags: xcode, core-data

I followed a tutorial to develop a simple application using Core Data in Xcode.

Now every time I open a "Navigation based" application with Core Data support, it opens with code I wrote for the sample app, including the Core Data stuff. So, when I create a blank application and run it just after creating it, it gives me the sample application I created.

Is this a bug or am I missing anything? This is driving me crazy please help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've over written the template used to create the basis for a new app. Try re-installing the templates if you can find them. If not, you may have to reinstall XCode.

The templates may be in one of these locations:

> “/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates” and “/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates”. [Source](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/05/19/custom-xcode-template-for-iphone-development/)

Comment: It didnt work ,reinstalling xcode didnt work either .I ended up switching to Lion with new xcode version